# how can i store the expired products in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, syntax-error

#this the code in controller #

```
public function index()
    {
       
    $expired_product = Product::select('expiry_date')
    ->whereNotNull('expiry_date', "<", Now())->get();
      
    return $expired_product; 
    }
```

Comment: hi , @th tom, you want to store it, or get it?

Comment: Hello! Make sure your question is detailed and you have an example input output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get expired products, you can use basic [where](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses):

```
 $expired_product = Product::where('expiry_date', "<", Now())->get();

 return $expired_product;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

To get the expired product you can use [WhereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries)

```
 public function index()
 {
     $expired_product = Product::select('expiry_date')->WhereDate('expiry_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'))->get();
    
      
     return $expired_product;

}
```